# std::vector member functions

Tags: c++, stl

I saw this question in a book:

> What member functions of the std::vector are controlling the allocated memory ?

Can someone answer this?
 Thank you

Comment: How do you define "controlling"? Reallocating it? Changing the values stored inside? Something else?

Comment: I'm not sure, that how the question was asked in the book...i guess reallocating

Comment: So, you don't know what your actual question is?  Then why ask it?

Comment: @ Benjamin Lindley: for help, what else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocations of Container classes is managed by the underlying `Allocator` defined for each of them.
Almost All member functions will `control` the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The expected answer to this is probably `resize`, `reserve` and `clear` although the latter does *not* in fact control the allocated memory, it just resets the “known” size to zero without modifying the underlying buffer.

Answer (score 0):

All of them. None of them. It's an implementation detail. *You do not know and it does not matter*.

Comment: That's not quite true.  When a vector allocates memory, it invalidates all iterators into it.  When it doesn't, it only invalidates iterators past the element involved in the change.

Comment: You do know, because the Standard specifies when reallocation happens, and it does matter, because reallocation invalidates all pointers and iterators to the vector's contents, and because sometimes you need deterministic performance.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor may or may not allocate memory.

Other constructors will allocate memory if the vector is not initially empty, and may or may not if it is empty.

`operator=`, `assign`, `insert`, `push_back`, `reserve` and `resize` will reallocate memory if the new size or capacity exceeds the current capacity, and will not otherwise.

The destructor will free any allocated memory.

No other member function will change the memory allocation, although some may change or invalidate the memory contents.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k449z507(v=VS.100).aspx

There are limits to asking questions on this place that are answered by googling "vector member functions".

Comment: read my post again and try to figure it out what I have asked. thanks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.